# Function works if I put in the correct input initially, but if I try a wrong input and then enter the correct input, it gives me an attribute error

Tags: python, try-except

I have a try/except statement:

```
def get_file():
   
    myfile = input("Enter the name of the file to read:\n")

    try:
        open_myfile = open(myfile, "r")
        return open_myfile
    except:
        print('Could not open file.')
         
        get_file()
```

And then a function if the code works to check the spelling:

```
def checktext(textfile):

    sp = spellchecker(textfile)
   
    lines_text = textfile.readlines()
   
    true = 0
    false = 0
    for line in lines_text:
        for word in line.split():
            c_word = sp.check(word)
           
            if c_word == True:
                true =+ 1
            else:
                print("Possible Spelling Error on line", lines_text.index(line),":",c_word)
                false = false + 1
    percent = ((true)/(true+false))*100
    print(false, "words that passed the spell checker.")
    print(true, "words failed the spell checker.")
    print(percent, "% of words passed.")
```

This works if I input a usuable file initially. If I put input anything other than a usable file, it will allow me to input another usable file, however, the code then will give me the attribute error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'readlines'. I am not sure why the code works when I just put in the correct file and then doesn't if get_file() passes though the except statement.

Comment: Where are you calling checktext?

Comment: I suspect you want to check `open_myfile.exists()`... You can `open()` non existing files

Comment: Does `get_file` intentionally call itself?

Comment: Yes, because you need to `return get_file()`. Or else the first call **always returns `None` if you hit the `execept`**.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sorry, right after the checktext function I have myfile = get_file()
checktext(myfile)

Comment: But you should just use a `while` loop instead of recursion. That is more idiomatic in Python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this worked, thanks!